# Why does mvn archetype:generate build another project?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm trying to run `mvn archetype:generate` to create a simple maven project. However the commands starts building another maven project. I don't understand why this is happening. Please check out the attached image.

[image]

And finally `mvn archetype:generate` fails at the end. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an orphaned `pom.xml` on my desktop and this was causing the issue. Fixed it by deleting the orphaned file and the archetype generation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify **groupId** and the **artifactId** parameters (usually the *package/company* and the *name* of your application) like the example:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app-name
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

See the quick-start guide http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

You can also use an IDE like Eclipse to generate a new Maven project using the more user-frendly wizard..

> *And finally mvn archetype:generate fails at the end.*

**May be normal if you have just installed Maven, according to documentation in the link:** 
*"This is because Maven is downloading the most recent artifacts (plugin jars and other files) into your local repository. You may also need to execute the command a couple of times before it succeeds."*

Anyway, please post the error to understend more.

Comment: Thank you @zerologiko, however my problem seems that I had an accidental pom.xml on my desktop.

Comment: I see now in the attached image that Maven was trying to build an Android project :)